# Facebook C# or FaceSharp

Tags: facebook

There are a couple of popular libraries for developing Facebook apps in C# on codeplex.
FaceSharp
Facebook C#

If you have experience with either one, please provide the Pros and Cons for each.  I am planning to develop a Silverlight facebook app which will run in Canvas and on a public site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i would vote to K[Microsoft's Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).Works well and provides you everything you want FQL or Async Get .i think you should go for it